# zipfile.BadZipFile: Bad CRC-32 when extracting a password protected .zip & .zip goes corrupt on extract

Tags: python, extract, zip, crc32

I am trying to extract a password protected .zip which has a .txt document (Say `Congrats.txt` for this case). Now `Congrats.txt` has text in it thus its not 0kb in size. Its placed in a .zip (For the sake of the thread lets name this .zip `zipv1.zip`) with the password `dominique` for the sake of this thread. That password is stored among other words and names within another .txt (Which we'll name it as `file.txt` for the sake of  this question).

Now if I run the code below by doing `python Program.py -z zipv1.zip -f file.txt` (Assuming all these files are in the same folder as `Program.py`) my program displays `dominique` as the correct password for the `zipv1.zip` among the other words/passwords in `file.txt` and extracts the `zipv1.zip` but the `Congrats.txt` is empty and has the size of 0kb.

Now my code is as follows:

```
import argparse
import multiprocessing
import zipfile

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Unzips a password protected .zip", usage="Program.py -z zip.zip -f file.txt")
# Creates -z arg
parser.add_argument("-z", "--zip", metavar="", required=True, help="Location and the name of the .zip file.")
# Creates -f arg
parser.add_argument("-f", "--file", metavar="", required=True, help="Location and the name of file.txt.")
args = parser.parse_args()


def extract_zip(zip_filename, password):
    try:
        zip_file = zipfile.ZipFile(zip_filename)
        zip_file.extractall(pwd=password)
        print(f"[+] Password for the .zip: {password.decode('utf-8')} \n")
    except:
        # If a password fails, it moves to the next password without notifying the user. If all passwords fail, it will print nothing in the command prompt.
        pass


def main(zip, file):
    if (zip == None) | (file == None):
        # If the args are not used, it displays how to use them to the user.
        print(parser.usage)
        exit(0)
    # Opens the word list/password list/dictionary in "read binary" mode.
    txt_file = open(file, "rb")
    # Allows 8 instances of Python to be ran simultaneously.
    with multiprocessing.Pool(8) as pool:
        # "starmap" expands the tuples as 2 separate arguments to fit "extract_zip"
        pool.starmap(extract_zip, [(zip, line.strip()) for line in txt_file])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(args.zip, args.file)
```

However if I another zip (`zipv2.zip`) with the same method as `zipv1.zip` with only difference being `Congrats.txt` is in a folder which the folder is zipped alongside `Congrats.txt` I do get the same results as `zipv1.zip` but this time `Congrats.txt` extracted along the folder it was in, and `Congrats.txt` was intact; the text in it and the size of it was intact.

So to solve this I tried reading [zipfile's documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html) where I found out that if a password doesn't match the .zip it throws a `RuntimeError`. So I did changed `except:` in the code to `except RuntimeError:` and got this error when trying to unzip `zipv1.zip`:

```
(venv) C:\Users\USER\Documents\Jetbrains\PyCharm\Program>Program.py -z zipv1.zip -f file.txt
[+] Password for the .zip: dominique

multiprocessing.pool.RemoteTraceback:
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 121, in worker
result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 47, in starmapstar
return list(itertools.starmap(args[0], args[1]))
  File "C:\Users\USER\Documents\Jetbrains\PyCharm\Program\Program.py", line 16, in extract_zip
zip_file.extractall(pwd=password)
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\zipfile.py", line 1594, in extractall
self._extract_member(zipinfo, path, pwd)
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\zipfile.py", line 1649, in _extract_member
shutil.copyfileobj(source, target)
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\shutil.py", line 79, in copyfileobj
buf = fsrc.read(length)
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\zipfile.py", line 876, in read
data = self._read1(n)
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\zipfile.py", line 966, in _read1
self._update_crc(data)
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\zipfile.py", line 894, in _update_crc
raise BadZipFile("Bad CRC-32 for file %r" % self.name)
zipfile.BadZipFile: Bad CRC-32 for file 'Congrats.txt'
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USER\Documents\Jetbrains\PyCharm\Program\Program.py", line 38, in <module>
main(args.zip, args.file)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Documents\Jetbrains\PyCharm\Program\Program.py", line 33, in main
pool.starmap(extract_zip, [(zip, line.strip()) for line in txt_file])
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 276, in starmap
return self._map_async(func, iterable, starmapstar, chunksize).get()
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 657, in get
raise self._value
zipfile.BadZipFile: Bad CRC-32 for file 'Congrats.txt'
```

The same results happpen though; password was found in `file.txt`, `zipv1.zip` was extracted but `Congrats.txt` was empty and 0kb in size. So I ran the program again, but for `zipv2.zip` this time and got this as a result:

```
(venv) C:\Users\USER\Documents\Jetbrains\PyCharm\Program>Program.py -z zipv2.zip -f file.txt
[+] Password for the .zip: dominique

multiprocessing.pool.RemoteTraceback:
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 121, in worker
result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 47, in starmapstar
return list(itertools.starmap(args[0], args[1]))
  File "C:\Users\USER\Documents\Jetbrains\PyCharm\Program\Program.py", line 16, in extract_zip
zip_file.extractall(pwd=password)
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\zipfile.py", line 1594, in extractall
self._extract_member(zipinfo, path, pwd)
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\zipfile.py", line 1649, in _extract_member
shutil.copyfileobj(source, target)
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\shutil.py", line 79, in copyfileobj
buf = fsrc.read(length)
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\zipfile.py", line 876, in read
data = self._read1(n)
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\zipfile.py", line 966, in _read1
self._update_crc(data)
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\zipfile.py", line 894, in _update_crc
raise BadZipFile("Bad CRC-32 for file %r" % self.name)
zipfile.BadZipFile: Bad CRC-32 for file 'Congrats.txt'
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USER\Documents\Jetbrains\PyCharm\Program\Program.py", line 38, in <module>
main(args.zip, args.file)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Documents\Jetbrains\PyCharm\Program\Program.py", line 33, in main
pool.starmap(extract_zip, [(zip, line.strip()) for line in txt_file])
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 276, in starmap
return self._map_async(func, iterable, starmapstar, chunksize).get()
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 657, in get
raise self._value
zipfile.BadZipFile: Bad CRC-32 for file 'Congrats.txt'
```

Again, same results; where the folder was extracted successfully and `Congrats.txt` was also extracted with the text inside it and the size of it was intact.

I did take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48745258/zipfile-badzipfile-bad-crc-32-for-file-read-only-file) similar thread, as well as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5624669/strange-badzipfile-bad-crc-32-problem) thread but they were no help. I also checked [zipfile's documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html) but it wasn't helpful regarding the issue.

### Edit

Now after implementing `with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_filename, 'r') as zip_file:` for some unknown and weird reason; the program can read/process a small word list/password list/dictionary but can't if its large(?).

What I mean by that is that say a .txt document is present in `zipv1.zip`; named `Congrats.txt` with the text `You have cracked the .zip!`. The same .txt is present in `zipv2.zip` aswell, but this time placed in a folder named `ZIP Contents` then zipped/password protected. The password is `dominique` for both of the zips.

Do note that each .zip was generated using `Deflate` compression method and `ZipCrypto` encryption in 7zip.

Now that password is in `Line 35` (35/52 lines)`John The Ripper Jr.txt` and in `Line 1968` for `John The Ripper.txt` (1968/3106 lines).

Now if you do `python Program.py -z zipv1 -f "John The Ripper Jr.txt"` in your CMD (or IDE of your choice); it will create a folder named `Extracted` and place `Congrats.txt` with the sentence we previously set. Same goes for `zipv2` but `Congrats.txt` will be in `ZIP Contents` folder which is inside the `Extracted` folder. No trouble extracting the .zips in this instance.

But if you try the same thing with `John The Ripper.txt` i.e `python Program.py -z zipv1 -f "John The Ripper.txt"` in your CMD (or IDE of your choice) it will create the `Extracted` folder both of the zips; just like `John The Ripper Jr.txt` but this time `Congrats.txt` will be **empty** for both of them for some unknown reason.

My code and all necessary files are as follows:

```
import argparse
import multiprocessing
import zipfile

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Unzips a password protected .zip by performing a brute-force attack.", usage="Program.py -z zip.zip -f file.txt")
# Creates -z arg
parser.add_argument("-z", "--zip", metavar="", required=True, help="Location and the name of the .zip file.")
# Creates -f arg
parser.add_argument("-f", "--file", metavar="", required=True, help="Location and the name of the word list/password list/dictionary.")
args = parser.parse_args()


def extract_zip(zip_filename, password):
    try:
        with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_filename, 'r') as zip_file:
            zip_file.extractall('Extracted', pwd=password)
            print(f"[+] Password for the .zip: {password.decode('utf-8')} \n")
    except:
        # If a password fails, it moves to the next password without notifying the user. If all passwords fail, it will print nothing in the command prompt.
        pass


def main(zip, file):
    if (zip == None) | (file == None):
        # If the args are not used, it displays how to use them to the user.
        print(parser.usage)
        exit(0)
    # Opens the word list/password list/dictionary in "read binary" mode.
    txt_file = open(file, "rb")
    # Allows 8 instances of Python to be ran simultaneously.
    with multiprocessing.Pool(8) as pool:
        # "starmap" expands the tuples as 2 separate arguments to fit "extract_zip"
        pool.starmap(extract_zip, [(zip, line.strip()) for line in txt_file])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Program.py - z zipname.zip -f filename.txt
    main(args.zip, args.file)
```

[Program.py](https://anonfile.com/h0rdV7s7b8/Program_py)

[zipv1.zip](https://anonfile.com/70qaV5s0b3/zipv1_zip)

[zipv2.zip](https://anonfile.com/81q9V9s1b9/zipv2_zip)

[John The Ripper Jr.txt](https://anonfile.com/4fqbV5s2b7/John_The_Ripper_Jr_txt)

[John The Ripper.txt](https://anonfile.com/6cq0V5s2b5/John_The_Ripper_txt)

[John The Ripper v2.txt](https://anonfile.com/y4h3Wcs0b5/John_The_Ripper_v2_txt)

I am unsure why this is happening and cannot find an answer for this issue anywhere. Its totally unknown from what I can tell and I can't find a way to debug or solve this issue.

This continues to occur regardless of different word/password lists. Tried generating more .zips with the same `Congrats.txt` but with different passwords from different word lists/password lists/dictionaries. Same method; a larger and smaller version of the .txt was used and same results as above were achieved.

**BUT** I did find out that if I cut out the first 2k words in `John The Ripper.txt` and make a new .txt; say `John The Ripper v2.txt`; the .zip is extracted successfully, `Extracted` folder appears and `Congrats.txt` is present with the text inside it. So I believe it has to do with the lines after the password is at. So in this case `Line 1968`; where the script doesn't stop after `Line 1968`? I am not sure why does this work though. It isn't a solution but a step towards the solution I guess...

### Edit 2

So I tried using a "pool terminating" code:

```
import argparse
import multiprocessing
import zipfile

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Unzips a password protected .zip by performing a brute-force attack using", usage="Program.py -z zip.zip -f file.txt")
# Creates -z arg
parser.add_argument("-z", "--zip", metavar="", required=True, help="Location and the name of the .zip file.")
# Creates -f arg
parser.add_argument("-f", "--file", metavar="", required=True, help="Location and the name of the word list/password list/dictionary.")
args = parser.parse_args()


def extract_zip(zip_filename, password, queue):
    try:
        with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_filename, "r") as zip_file:
            zip_file.extractall('Extracted', pwd=password)
            print(f"[+] Password for the .zip: {password.decode('utf-8')} \n")
            queue.put("Done")  # Signal success
    except:
        # If a password fails, it moves to the next password without notifying the user. If all passwords fail, it will print nothing in the command prompt.
        pass


def main(zip, file):
    if (zip == None) | (file == None):
        print(parser.usage)  # If the args are not used, it displays how to use them to the user.
        exit(0)
    # Opens the word list/password list/dictionary in "read binary" mode.
    txt_file = open(file, "rb")

    # Create a Queue
    manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
    queue = manager.Queue()

    with multiprocessing.Pool(8) as pool:  # Allows 8 instances of Python to be ran simultaneously.
        pool.starmap_async(extract_zip, [(zip, line.strip(), queue) for line in txt_file])  # "starmap" expands the tuples as 2 separate arguments to fit "extract_zip"
        pool.close()
        queue.get(True)  # Wait for a process to signal success
        pool.terminate()  # Terminate the pool
        pool.join()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(args.zip, args.file)  # Program.py -z zip.zip -f file.txt.
```

Now if I use this both zips are extracted successfully, just like the previous instances. **BUT** this time `zipv1.zip`'s  `Congrats.txt` is intact; has the message inside it. But the same thing cannot be said regarding `zipv2.zip` as its still empty.

Comment: Can you share your ZIP file?

Comment: [zipv1](https://anonfile.com/BcH5P7s5b7/zipv1_zip)
[zipv2](https://anonfile.com/76H3P8saba/zipv2_zip)

Both were generated with 7zip as WinRAR zipped files don't extract with zipfile (If password protected). Used `Deflate` as compression method and `ZipCrypto` as encryption method in 7zip.

Comment: I was able to successfully run the code on both *.zip* files, no exception, file was extracted, using a dummy *file.txt* consisting of 12 lines (out of which one was obviously *dominique*).

Comment: A friend said the same thing as he made his own wordlist/.txt with a few dozen words; one being `dominique` of-course. Then I told him to try the same thing with the wordlist I used ([Link](https://anonfile.com/H7IaU6scb6/John_The_Ripper_txt)) and he told me he did get an empty .txt when the password was found. So this issue has to do with the length of the wordlist/file.txt somehow. I tried killing the multiprocess as soon as a password was found as seen [here](https://gist.github.com/Arszilla/9453886b17ced60879563fe56819679e) but it was useless...

Comment: I was leaning to the *subprocess* hypothesis too. But I was able to run the program with the new *.txt* file, I even doubled it (also tried with 0, 1, 2 occurrences of *dominique*) with *Python* *3.6* and *3.7* *32/64*,(who support **f** strings), but it still works. :(

Comment: Extracting the .zip is not the issue; the .txt inside the zip gets corrupt/erased; thats the issue. Does the .txt inside the .zip still have the "You have cracked the .zip!" text and is 1kb in size?

Comment: Yes, I've just noticed the ***except*** / ***pass***. I am able to reproduce, narrowed it down, but I can't believe what I see. I have to investigate more before posting an answer.

Comment: @CristiFati Not having the .txt remain preserved/not corrupt? Yea, been trying to find an answer for it for days now. I’ll open a new post as this post might not be the most suitable post for it. I’ll post a link under this message in a bit; probably in 30 mins.

Comment: The file is empty. You should probably edit this post instead, and also add the download link to files you tried with in the question (rather than comments). Also the 2 zip files are reversed.

Comment: @CristiFati i did mention that in my reply to Alderven . But thanks for the suggestion. If you got a post name suggestion, I’ll take it as I am in “guided-mode” when asking questions, sadly.

Comment: @CristiFati Thread is up. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54549321/zipfile-extract-goes-corrupt-if-a-word-password-list-is-too-long-big)

Comment: I do not understand. Why did you created another question instead of modifying the current one?

Comment: I didnt think of that. I'll update the post here then, and delete the other. **EDIT** Done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for the long pause ... It seems you've got yourself into a bit of a pickle.

***Recap***:

- Working on a password protected *.zip* file
- Brute force (*ciobaneste*) is attempted, using passwords from a file
- The correct password is in the (previous step) file, but in spite of that, some files aren't properly extracted

### 1. Investigation

The scenario is complex (quite far away from an ***M**CVE*, I'd say), there are many things that can be blamed for the behavior.

Starting with the *zipv1.zip* / *zipv2.zip* mismatch. On a closer look, it appears that, ***zipv2* is messed up as well**. If things are easy to spot for *zipv1* (*Congrats.txt* being the only file), for *zipv2*, *"ZIP Contents/Black-Large.png"* is being ***0* sized**. 
It is reproducible with any file, and more: **it applies to 1<sup>st</sup> entry (which is not a *dir*) returned by *zf.namelist***.

So, things start to get a little bit clearer:

- File contents is being unpacked, due to *dominique* being present in the password file (don't know what happens til that point)
- At a later point, the *.zip*'s 1<sup>st</sup> entry is truncated to *0* bytes

Looking at the exceptions thrown when attempting to extract files using a wrong password, there are 3 types (out of which the last 2 can be grouped together):

1. **`RuntimeError: Bad password for file ...`**
2. Others:

   - **`zlib.error: Error -3 while decompressing data ...`**
   - **`zipfile.BadZipFile: Bad CRC-32 for file ...`**

I created an archive file of my own. For consistency's sake, I'll be using it from now on, but everything would apply to any other file as well.

- Content:

  - *DummyFile0.zip* (*10* bytes) - containing: *0123456789*
  - *DummyFile1.zip* (*10* bytes) - containing: *0000000000*
  - *DummyFile2.zip* (*10* bytes) - containing: *AAAAAAAAAA*
- Archived the 3 files with *Total Commander* (*v9.21a*) internal *Zip* packer, password protecting it with *dominique* (*zip2.0* encryption). The resulting archive (named it *arc0.zip* (but name is not relevant)), is *392* bytes long

*code00.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import sys
import zipfile


def main(*argv):
    arc_name = argv[0] if argv else "./arc0.zip"
    pwds = (
        #b"dominique",
        #b"dickhead",
        b"coco",
    )
    #pwds = [item.strip() for item in open("orig/John The Ripper.txt.orig", "rb").readlines()]
    print("Unpacking (password protected: dominique) {:s},"
          " using a list of predefined passwords ...".format(arc_name))
    if not os.path.isfile(arc_name):
        raise SystemExit("Archive file must exist!\nExiting.")
    faulty_pwds = list()
    good_pwds = list()
    with zipfile.ZipFile(arc_name, "r") as zip_file:
        print("Zip names: {:}\n".format(zip_file.namelist()))
        for idx, pwd in enumerate(pwds):
            try:
                zip_file.extractall("Extracted", pwd=pwd)
            except:
                exc_cls, exc_inst, exc_tb = sys.exc_info()
                if exc_cls != RuntimeError:
                    print("Exception caught when using password ({:d}): [{:}] ".format(idx, pwd))
                    print("    {:}: {:}".format(exc_cls, exc_inst))
                    faulty_pwds.append(pwd)
            else:
                print("Success using password ({:d}): [{:}] ".format(idx, pwd))
                good_pwds.append(pwd)
            input()
    print("\nFaulty passwords: {:}\nGood passwords: {:}".format(faulty_pwds, good_pwds))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} {:03d}bit on {:s}\n".format(" ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")),
                                                   64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.\n")
    sys.exit(rc)
```

**Output**:

> ```bat
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q054532010]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.06.08_test0\Scripts\python.exe" ./code00.py ./arc0.zip
> Python 3.6.8 (tags/v3.6.8:3c6b436a57, Dec 24 2018, 00:16:47) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] 064bit on win32
>
> Unpacking (password protected: dominique) arc0.zip, using a list of predefined passwords ...
> Zip names: ['DummyFile0.txt', 'DummyFile1.txt', 'DummyFile2.txt']
>
> Exception caught when using password (1189): [b'mariah']
>     <class 'zlib.error'>: Error -3 while decompressing data: invalid code lengths set
> Exception caught when using password (1446): [b'zebra']
>     <class 'zlib.error'>: Error -3 while decompressing data: invalid block type
> Exception caught when using password (1477): [b'1977']
>     <class 'zlib.error'>: Error -3 while decompressing data: invalid block type
> Success using password (1967): [b'dominique']
> Exception caught when using password (2122): [b'hank']
>     <class 'zlib.error'>: Error -3 while decompressing data: invalid code lengths set
> Exception caught when using password (2694): [b'solomon']
>     <class 'zlib.error'>: Error -3 while decompressing data: invalid distance code
> Exception caught when using password (2768): [b'target']
>     <class 'zlib.error'>: Error -3 while decompressing data: invalid block type
> Exception caught when using password (2816): [b'trish']
>     <class 'zlib.error'>: Error -3 while decompressing data: invalid code lengths set
> Exception caught when using password (2989): [b'coco']
>     <class 'zlib.error'>: Error -3 while decompressing data: invalid stored block lengths
>
> Faulty passwords: [b'mariah', b'zebra', b'1977', b'hank', b'solomon', b'target', b'trish', b'coco']
> Good passwords: [b'dominique']
>
> Done.
> ```

Looking at *ZipFile.extractall* code, it tries to extract all the members. The 1<sup>st</sup> raises an exception, so it starts to be clearer why it behaves the way it does. But why the behavioral difference, when attempting to extract items using 2 wrong passwords? 
As seen in the tracebacks of the 2 different thrown exception types, the answer lies somewhere at the end of *ZipFile.open*.

After more investigations, it turns out it's because of a

### 2. Collision determined by *zip* encryption weakness

According to [[UT.CS]: dmitri-report-f15-16.pdf - Password-based encryption in ZIP files](https://courses.cs.ut.ee/MTAT.07.022/2015_fall/uploads/Main/dmitri-report-f15-16.pdf) ((last) **emphasis** is mine):

> **3.1 Traditional PKWARE encryption**
>
> The original encryption scheme, commonly referred to as the PKZIP cipher, was designed by
> Roger Schaffely [1]. In [5] Biham and Kocher showed that the cipher is weak and demonstrated
> an attack requiring 13 bytes of plaintext. Further attacks have been developed, some of which
> require no user provided plaintext at all [6].
> The PKZIP cipher is essentially a stream cipher, i.e. input is encrypted by generating a pseudo-
> random key stream and XOR-ing it with the plaintext. The internal state of the cipher consists
> of three 32-bit words: **key0**, **key1** and **key2**. These are initialized to **0x12345678**, **0x23456789** and
> **0x34567890**, respectively. A core step of the algorithm involves updating the three keys using a
> single byte of input...
>
> ...
>
> Before encrypting a file in the archive, 12 random bytes are first prepended to its compressed
> contents and the resulting bytestream is then encrypted. Upon decryption, the first 12 bytes
> need to be discarded. According to the specification, this is done in order to render a plaintext
> attack on the data ineffective.
> The specification also states that out of the 12 prepended bytes, **only the first 11 are actually
> random, the last byte is equal to the high order byte of the CRC-32 of the uncompressed
> contents of the file. This gives the ability to quickly verify whether a given password is correct
> by comparing the last byte of the decrypted 12 byte header to the high order byte of the actual
> CRC-32 value that is included in the local file header**. This can be done before decrypting the
> rest of the file.

Other references:

- [[CacheFly.PKWare]: APPNOTE.TXT - .ZIP File Format Specification](https://pkware.cachefly.net/webdocs/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT).

The algorithm weakness: due to the fact that differentiation is done on **one byte only**, for ***256* different (and carefully chosen)** wrong passwords, there will be **one (at least) that will generate the same number as the correct password**.

The algorithm discards most of the wrong passwords, but there are some that it doesn't.

Going back: when a file is attempted to be extracted using a password:

- If the "hash" computed on the file cipher's last byte is different than file *CRC*'s high order byte, an exception is thrown
- **But**, if they are equal:

  - A new file stream is open for writing (emptying the file if already existing)
  - The decompression is attempted:

    - For wrong passwords (that have passed the above check), the decompression will fail (but the file is already emptied)

As seen from the output above, for my (*.zip*) file there are ***8*** passwords that mess it up. Note that:

- For each archive file the result differs
- The **member** file name and content are relevant (at least for the 1<sup>st</sup> one). Changing any of those will yield different results (for the "same" archive file)

Here's a test based on data from my *.zip* file:

> ```py
> >>> import zipfile
> >>>
> >>> zd_coco = zipfile._ZipDecrypter(b"coco")
> >>> zd_dominique = zipfile._ZipDecrypter(b"dominique")
> >>> zd_other = zipfile._ZipDecrypter(b"other")
> >>> cipher = b'\xd1\x86y ^\xd77gRzZ\xee'  # Member (1st) file cipher: 12 bytes starting from archive offset 44
> >>>
> >>> crc = 2793719750  # Member (1st) file CRC - archive bytes: 14 - 17
> >>> hex(crc)
> '0xa684c7c6'
> >>> for zd in (zd_coco, zd_dominique, zd_other):
> ...     print(zd, [hex(zd(c)) for c in cipher])
> ...
> <zipfile._ZipDecrypter object at 0x0000021E8DA2E0F0> ['0x1f', '0x58', '0x89', '0x29', '0x89', '0xe', '0x32', '0xe7', '0x2', '0x31', '0x70', '0xa6']
> <zipfile._ZipDecrypter object at 0x0000021E8DA2E160> ['0xa8', '0x3f', '0xa2', '0x56', '0x4c', '0x37', '0xbb', '0x60', '0xd3', '0x5e', '0x84', '0xa6']
> <zipfile._ZipDecrypter object at 0x0000021E8DA2E128> ['0xeb', '0x64', '0x36', '0xa3', '0xca', '0x46', '0x17', '0x1a', '0xfb', '0x6d', '0x6c', '0x4e']
> >>>  # As seen, the last element of the first 2 arrays (coco and dominique) is 0xA6 (166), which is the same as the first byte of the CRC
> ```

I did some tests with other unpacking engines (with default arguments):

1. *WinRar*: for a wrong password the file is untouched, but for a faulty one it is truncated (same as here)
2. *7-Zip*: It asks the user whether to overwrite the file, and it ovewrites it regardless of the decompression result
3. *Total Commander*'s internal (*Zip*) unpacker: same as ***#2.***

### 3. Conclusion

- I see this as a *ZipFile* bug. Specifying such a faulty (and wrong) password shouldn't overwrite the existing file (if any). Or at least, behavior should be consistent (for all wrong passwords)
- A quick browse didn't reveal any bug on *Python*
- I don't see an easy fix, as:

  - The *Zip* algorithm can't be improved (to better check whether a password is *OK*)
  - I thought of a couple of fixes, but they will either negatively impact performance or could introduce regressions in some (corner) cases

I've submitted **[[GitHub]: python/cpython - [3.6] bpo-36247: zipfile - extract truncates (existing) file when bad password provided (zip encryption weakness)](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/12242)** which **was closed for branch *3.6*** (which is in *security fixes only* mode). Not sure what its outcome it's going to be (in other branches), but anyway, it won't be available anytime soon (in the next months, let's say).

As an alternative, you could download the patch, and apply the changes locally. Check [[SO]: Run / Debug a Django application's UnitTests from the mouse right click context menu in PyCharm Community Edition? (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42989490/4788546) (**Patching *UTRunner*** section) for how to apply patches on *Win* (basically, every line that starts with **one "+"** sign goes in, and every line that starts with **one "-"** sign goes out).
You could copy *zipfile.py* from *Python*'s *dir* to your project (or some "personal") *dir* and patch that file, if you want to keep your *Python* installation pristine.

Comment: So what you are telling me is that my issue is being caused by zipfile itself, right? Regardless what my code is (or will be), due to how zipfile acts it will always break my zips/extracts? If thats the case, is there an alternative?

Comment: Yes. the core problem is in the zip compression core itself, the result is the way of that problem being handled by *zipfile* (and other tools). But wasn;t my answer clear enough? Anyway, I found a solution, submitted it to *Python*, but ran into all kinds of process and documents issue. Will update the answer shortly.

Comment: Tried it with your fix [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/12242/commits/f16b12c12a8c33f2f029f6ca41707b7de9ee3769) and it works! Thanks

If your edits are accepted, I assume it will be live on the next Python, right? Not sure how these things go as I see myself as a newbie/amateur in Python.

Also if I make a copy of `zipfile.py`, I shouldn't name it the same as the file right? `zippy.py` instead of `zipfile.py` right?

Comment: As I said it might be rejected. If it is accepted it will be in the next release (didn't check when that will be, but I assume it will take some time). In the mean time you could solve your problem locally. From what am I concerned it would be ok to modify your original *zipfile.py* (if you backed it up before), so that if it turns out that my fix introduces some nasty issues (I don't think it's the case) you can restore it. Or you could go on the safe side and copy the file in your project and do the changes there. I'd suggest against renaming it (e.g. *zippy* or some other name), ...

Comment: (continuation) since you'd have to modify all the files that import it. That's why (but only if you're not sure, I'd still go by modifying the original one), create a dir that contains files like this one, and modify them only in there. Then make sure the dir is in *PYTHONPATH* so the modules are loaded before the ones with the same name from standard *Python* library.. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42705279/strange-error-while-using-pycharm-to-debug-pyqt-gui/55066132#55066132. If this answers your question, please mark it as a solution. And an upvote would be nice as well :) Thx.

Comment: Thanks @CristiFati for the amazing investigation here and opening those issues on the Python project as well!

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and a bit of digging around revealed that it was my choice of encryption for the zip file that was the problem. I changed from the default offered by 7-Zip, ZipCrypto, to AES-256 and all was well.

Comment: Could you please detail?